# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{h(x)}{e^x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Say we know that the following holds:
$$h(x) \leq 7e^x \leq \frac{3h(x)}{x}$$
Evaluate the following limit:$$\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{h(x)}{e^x}$$

I'm aware of the squeeze theorem, but I'm not sure how to "squeeze" the $\frac{h(x)}{e^x}$ algebraically. I thought about inverting the whole thing (not sure if that's even allowed) and ended up with $21 \leq \frac{h(x)}{e^x} <= 21$ but that doesn't seem to be accurate. Would appreciate some help here, thanks in advance!

Comment: @mrsamy nope, why would it be a typo?

Comment: sorry, I misread your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

You have two inequalities,
$$
h(x)\le 7e^x,\quad 7e^x\le\frac{3h(x)}{x}
$$
each of which gives you an inequality for $\frac{h(x)}{e^x}$.

Comment: Oh right! That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

We know that $$(\forall x>0) \;\;e^x>0$$

So

$$h(x)\le 7e^x\le\frac{3h(x)}{x}\implies$$

$$\frac{7x}{3}\le \frac{h(x)}{e^x}\le 7$$